# Angular 2: How to create form elements after receiving data from REST call.

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to Angular 2. I am trying to generate a FormArray of FormGroup elements(rendering on the html as checkboxes) in Angular 2 typescript:

```
buildForm(): void {

    let allProducts: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
        let fg = new FormGroup({});
        fg.addControl(this.products[i].productId, new FormControl(false));
        allProducts.push(fg);
    }

    this.accountCreateForm = this.fb.group({
        productIds: allProducts
    });

    this.accountCreateForm.valueChanges
        .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

    this.onValueChanged();

}
```

I am getting the list of products by REST call in ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
    this.buildForm();
}   
loadData(): void {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(list => {
        this.products = list;
    });
}
```

On the html I have the following:

```
<div class="column-2" formArrayName="productIds">
    <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index">
        <label formGroupName="{{i}}">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{product.name}}"
                   formControlName="{{product.productId}}"
                   class="styled" checked>
            {{product.displayName}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'productIds -> 0'
at _throwError (vendor.dll.js:14530) [angular]
at setUpFormContainer (vendor.dll.js:14503) [angular]
at FormGroupDirective.addFormGroup (vendor.dll.js:26751) [angular]
at FormGroupName.AbstractFormGroupDirective.ngOnInit (vendor.dll.js:25977) [angular]
at Wrapper_FormGroupName.ngDoCheck (/ReactiveFormsModule/FormGroupName/wrapper.ngfactory.js:34) [angular]
at View_AccountCreateComponent27.detectChangesInternal (/App/AccountCreateComponent/component.ngfactory.js:935) [angular]
at View_AccountCreateComponent27.AppView.detectChanges (vendor.dll.js:123458) [angular]
at View_AccountCreateComponent27.DebugAppView.detectChanges (vendor.dll.js:123653) [angular]
at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (vendor.dll.js:123791) [angular]
at View_AccountCreateComponent3.detectChangesInternal (/App/AccountCreateComponent/component.ngfactory.js:3392) [angular]
at View_AccountCreateComponent3.AppView.detectChanges (vendor.dll.js:123458) [angular]
at View_AccountCreateComponent3.DebugAppView.detectChanges (vendor.dll.js:123653) [angular]
at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (vendor.dll.js:123791) [angular]
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AccountCreateComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/App/AccountCreateComponent/component.ngfactory.js:5380) [angular]
```

So the issue I see is that the form component requires data to be there before buildForm is called.
I am new to Angular 2, Observables, Promises and stuff. 
So the question is what is the best way to do it in Angular 2 So that buildForm can wait until the data arrives. Or is there a way I can add the elements on the form later after the data arrives? Probably generate them on firing of some event?
Some example code would be helpful.

Comment: Works fine if I hardcode the data in the product.service rather than getting from REST call:     
getProducts(): Observable<Array<Product>> {
        return Observable.of([{'productId': '1', 'name': 'Product 1', 'displayName': 'Product 1'},
            {'productId': '3', 'name': 'Product 3', 'displayName': 'Product 3'}]);
//        return this.restangular.all('products').getList();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (I didn't test though):

```js
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){
  this.myFormArray = this.fb.array([])
  this.accountCreateForm= this.fb.group({
    productIds:this.myFormArray
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts().switchMap(list => {
        this.products = list;
        let arr=this.myFormArray;
        list.forEach((item,index)=>{
            let fg = new FormGroup({});
            fg.addControl(item.productId, new FormControl(false));
            arr.push(fg);
        });
        this.onValueChanged(); // seems mandatory, weird, but, allright....
        return this.accountCreateForm.valueChanges;
    }).do(data=>this.onValueChanged(data))
    .subscribe();
}
```

```html
<div class="column-2" formArrayName="productIds">
    <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let item of myFormArray.controls; let i = index">
        <label [formGroup]="item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{products[i].name}}" formControlName="{{products[i].productId}}" class="styled">
            {{products[i].displayName}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```